# In Kubuntu 20.04, some applications do not use the global menu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gimp, inkscape, globalmenu

I am using Kubuntu 20.04. I added global menu to the panel. Most of the applications are using the global menu perfectly. But *Gimp*, *Inkscape* and *Texmaker* are not using the global menu at all.

How can I make these three applications to use the global menu?

**Update:**
Gimp and Inkscape - both are installed from official snap. Texmaker was installed from official ubuntu repository using apt.
GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.10.20
Inkscape version  1.0
Texmaker version 5.0.3

Comment: I think it's by design, same with Firefox

Comment: Please mention the source (snap? deb? std repo? ppa?) and versions of the applications.

Comment: The post has been updated according to the suggestion of DK Bose.

Comment: I am using flatpak and having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing some packages:

```
sudo apt install unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```